# Alternatives for `` in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, quotes, quoting

I have a code that is processed in the server which makes a huge string (which sometimes contains ' or " in it), so I need to have a good way of making that string while ignoring all of the quotes.

I've tried using `` but got this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in strict mode.

Please help!

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes

Comment: If you are getting a string *already*, then any quotes inside it shouldn't matter. If you are trying to get a string *literal* and then try to parse it as a string, that might lead to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you use to delimit your string, the odds are that you are going to end up with some data which uses that character.

Instead, change the server side code which generates the string so it properly escapes the data.

Since the JSON data format is a subset of JavaScript, you can use any JSON library to generate a JavaScript-compatible string literal.

Comment: The thing is that I put  that string as a <script> in an HTML page, so it adds columns to a table.
So how can I use a JSON for that?

Comment: @LironAvital — You have *something* which takes a string and writes it to the HTML document. Just pass that string through a JSON encoder first. It's impossible to be more specific than that because your question lacks a [mcve] and we have no idea what that *something* is.